# Two independent notifications

Tags: android

I've an alarmreceiver that fire a notification from broadcast. Runs perfectly. Now I added another notification and I like have 2 notifications indipendently. Starts first notification, later starts second notification, second notification cancel the first notification so I see only second. I need have 2 notification on notification bar. Also remove "flag cancel" does not runs.

My code (second notification):

```
String ns2 = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager2 = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns2);

            int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcherlight;
            CharSequence tickerText = not1[x];
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

            CharSequence contentTitle = "Casual";
            CharSequence contentText = not1[x];

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("com.example.myapp", null, context, NotifyCasual.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("notify", not1[x]);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 2, notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);



            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);


            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

            String Sound = prefs.getString("sound", "");
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

            final int HELLO2 = 1;

            mNotificationManager2.notify(HELLO2, notification);
```

Comment: are you giving different notification id to each notification?

Comment: Huh? mhmhm... no... how set an id? thanks

Comment: I just gave you answer see it and accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do like this.
When you are creating notification just follow this.

For 1st notification:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notifyDetails);
```

For 2nd notification:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(2, notifyDetails);
```

Comment: So, I've 2 class: first class with some notification of same type. Another class with other notification of same type.

Answer (score 1):

For getting a new notification everytime you have to pass different id each time for PendingIntent,

So you have to create a dynamic id

```
int id = 0; // declare globally and save the id.
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id,
                       notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
id = id + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

make you every notification intent unique by using setData.i use 
when=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()

try it as following code

```
    /*create intent for show notification details when user clicks notification*/
    Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_DATA, notificationData);

    /*create unique this intent from  other intent using setData */
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://"+when));
    /*create new task for each notification with pending intent so we set Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK */
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    /*get the system service that manage notification NotificationManager*/
    NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 

    /*build the notification*/
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .setWhen(when)
            .setContentText(notificationContent)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setSmallIcon(smalIcon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(notificationTitle)
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    /*Create notification with builder*/
    Notification notification=notificationBuilder.build();

    /*sending notification to system.Here we use unique id (when)for making different each notification
     * if we use same id,then first notification replace by the last notification*/
    notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);
```

Comment: for more info visit http://sanathnandasiri.blogspot.com/2012/12/android-notification-with.html